# How to install xhtml2pdf in Cloud9 using python 2.7?

Tags: python, django, xhtml2pdf, c9.io

I have tried to install xhtml2pdf for render pdf from html.I have followed the instructions bellow.

```
Installation

For python2.7:

pip install xhtml2pdf

To obtain the latest experimental version that has Python 3 support, please use a prerelease:

pip install --pre xhtml2pdf
```

but in this process , C9 shows me this error. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You're trying to install it with python 3 somehow. You can see that theres a line that references `File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py"`

Comment: but when i use --pre it shows me this error `File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xhtml2pdf/util.py", line 302
    raise Exception, "box not defined right way"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is solved by updating `six` package. I've uninstall the `six` package and again install the update one.

```
sudo pip install six
```

or

```
sudo pip install six -U
```